# How to write onclick for animating image continously?

Tags: android, android-animation

My code:

```
        moveBottomtoTop = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 320, -320);
        moveBottomtoTop.setDuration(1000);
        moveBottomtoTop.setRepeatCount(-1);
        moveBottomtoTop.setFillAfter(false);

        imageView01.startAnimation(moveBottomtoTop);

        imageView01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                imageView01.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

My xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/video_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/bubbles_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/l01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/pressed01"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cont_desc"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

But the onclick event doesn't work. And also the animation leaves trails. I've googled for it and found that applying padding="1dp" will solve, but no luck. And my animation view goes half behind the videoview and half above videoview. Please help me with these three issues. I just want to do a part of functionality from this app:[Bubbles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.squishythings.bubbles),i.e., moving the bubbles from bottom to top and squash when touched.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code inside the onClick and start the animation again :

```
moveLefttoRight.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```